# A fantastic puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking

**Explain why the string of letters below is equal to -1 somehow.**

---

```
           stuoedhteobntghkni → _ _ _ = -1
                                      
                                    
                                    
             432165879111013151716181214
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Split the letters in groups of five for easier indexing:

```
       stuoe dhteo bntgh kni
```

Split the long line of numbers and use as indexes:

> ```
>  4 3 2 1 6 5 8 7 9 11 10 13 15 17 16 18 12 14
>  o u t s d e t h e b  o  t  h  n  k  i  n  g
> ```

Looks like something is missing:

> *Outs**i**de the bo**x** th**i**nking*

The missing part is, indeed, three letters long. For the final step, interpret the missing parts as mathematics:

> $$ i \times i = i^2 = -1 $$

and there we have it.

EDIT: (thanks, @CatProgrammer) The topic calls the puzzle "fantastic"; I might go as far as saying some parts of it are entirely [imaginary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit).

Comment: Does the word "fantastic" have anything to do with the solution?

Answer (score 2):

stuoedhteobntghkni and 432165879111013151716181214 make

> Outsde the bo thnking

which makes:

> ixi

which makes:

> sqrt(-1)^2 = -1

Comment: Hi Will. This answer (though correct) would benefit from some clearer descriptions of the logic behind each 'make' or 'which makes'. The other answer really helps a reader to understand the solve process without having to do too much heavy lifting themselves. Just a spot of feedback! :)

Comment: @Stiv I totally agree.  I was rushing to be the first to solve it.  I realize my answer is in effect just hints.  Bass’ answer is better.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Fair enough - we've all been there...!